# That and which in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

I have some sentences that i want to know which one is correct:

- I'm trying to get trending tags with the number of posts **that** are
  tagged **with them**.
- I'm trying to get trending tags with the number of posts **which** are tagged **with them**.
- I'm trying to get trending tags with the number of posts **which** are tagged **with**.
- I'm trying to get trending tags with the number of posts **that** are tagged **with**.

Comment: The first. You cannot omit the *them* here, it's not grammatical. Both *that* and *which* would be understood, but *that* is more correct--*that* is used for restrictive clauses, filtering down a body of items to the ones that match a condition. *I am trying to get trending tags and the counts of posts using each tag* might be a bit nicer.

Comment: Do native-speakers use the same sentence without the `them`? like an ungrammatical sentence.

Comment: No, you really need the object here. If you think I am trying to enforce the fake rule 'do not end a clause with a preposition,' I am not--'I want to get all posts and the tags they are tagged with' is a perfectly valid sentence. You really need to provide the object in the sentence in your post.

Comment: @MikeGraham I got it, Thank you.

Comment: The first two only. The second two are ill-formed. _That_ and _which_ are both OK with restrictive relative clauses; there is no difference. In the last two ungrammatical sentences, the relative pronouns refer to _posts_, but there is no reference to _tags_, which is what _them_ in the first two refers to. Without the reference, the sentence fails.